# Dependencies for custom kotlin multiplatform project not in classpath

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I have created a multiplatform lib, and published it to maven central. I wanted to test it, but it doesn't seem like Gradle is importing all the libraries that my multiplatform project needs.

My multiplatform project build file: https://github.com/jan-tennert/DiscordKM/blob/master/build.gradle.kts

I mean IntelliJ is importing the libraries: [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqrPR.png)

But in code I see something like that: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqzUq.png)

And the program won't start because of "Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
" errors

You can maybe try to import my project yourself: (maven central)

```
implementation("io.github.jan-tennert.discordkm:DiscordKM:0.1")
```

Comment: And I mean the pom looks ok: https://search.maven.org/artifact/io.github.jan-tennert.discordkm/DiscordKM-jvm/0.1/jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nvm, I had to implement the common dependencies with api instead of implementation (on the multiplatform project side)